# Window Tester Pro for eclipse based application (AUT)

Tags: eclipse, swt, gui-testing, eclipse-rcptt

I have developed a standalone Eclipse-RCP application and I want to perform some GUI related automated testing.

I am currently using RCPTT and looking for other alternatives.

**Can anyone explain how to use Window Tester Pro GUI testing an application which has already been exported?**

Also, can you suggest any alternative to test our already exported Eclipse-RCP application?

Comment: I don't know Window Tester Pro GUI, but if you're looking for alternatives I can advise you [SWTBot](https://www.eclipse.org/swtbot/) to test Eclipse-based application. There is a [great tutorial on Vogella](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWTBot/article.html). Would it suit your needs?

Comment: @echebbi so far what i read is  the SWTBot is good to test the application in the coding stage. but we have already compiled and build a working exe application using eclipse as the based. we require a tool to now test these application . we are currently using rcptt are there any better alternatives

Comment: Can you explain to me what are reasons you are looking for alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Jubula is an alternative for already exported RCP applications but it also has its own disadvantages.
I can recommend you to use one or other if you tell me more about the nature of your application and your needs.